# bootstrap-vue: import specific css

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

I want to use a tooltip from the bootstrap-vue.
When I add

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css'
```

to get the tooltip style,
then the whole view of my application is changing. Is it possible to import css only to my tooltip?

Comment: have you found a way to import specific style from bootstrap-vue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import the tooltip component from the `src` folder, like this

```
import 'bootstrap-vue/src/components/tooltip'
```